# Naive Bayes with Laplace Smoothing Probabilities Not Adding Up

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, naive-bayes, laplace-smoothing

Let c refer to a class (such as Positive or Negative), and let w refer to a token or word.

Define

$count(w,c) = $ $counts \ w \  in\  class \  c$

$count(c)   = counts \  of \  words  \ in \  class \ c$

P(w|c)= $( count(w,c)+1 ) \div ( count(c)+|V|+1)$,

$|V|$ refers to the vocabulary (the words in the training set).

In particular, any unknown word will have probability
$ 1 \div count(c)+|V|+1 $

So my problem is let's say I have the following setup

### Training Set

1 : a, d, o ---> +

2 : a, g, w ---> +

3 : d, r, w ---> -

So using this

$|V| = 6$

But if I try to do this, the probabilities for the negative class dont add to 1.

$P(a|-) = (0+1) \div (3+6+1) = 0.1$

$P(d|-) = (1+1) \div (3+6+1) = 0.2$

$P(o|-) = (0+1) \div (3+6+1) = 0.1$

$P(g|-) = (0+1) \div (3+6+1) = 0.1$

$P(w|-) = (1+1) \div (3+6+1) = 0.2$

$P(r|-) = (1+1) \div (3+6+1) = 0.2$

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct equation for $P(w|c)$ should instead be

$P(w|c)= \frac{count(w,c)+1}{count(c)+|V|}$

assuming that there are $V$ words in class $c$. If you make this correction, all your probabilities add to $1$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much! And to be certain, count(c) is not unique words, its total words, yes?

Comment: Correct, $count(c)$ is the total number of words which appear in sentences in class $c$, and $count(w,c)$ is the total number of times that word $w$ appears in sentences in class $c$.